# TypeError: 'int' object is not an interator

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

i want to  get the RAM usage from a Windows machine with Python. Therefore im using the pysnmp libary. By executing the following code i get a error message saying:

```
  line 38, in getRamUsage
    error_indication, error_status, error_index, var_binds = next(iterator)
TypeError: 'int' object is not an iterator
```

```py
from pysnmp.hlapi.asyncore import *

def getRamUsage():
    iterator = getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                      CommunityData('public'),
                      UdpTransportTarget(('192.168.1.10', 161)),
                      ContextData(),
                      ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('1.3.6.1.2.1.25.2.3.1.6.2')),
                      lexicographicMode=False)
    error_indication, error_status, error_index, var_binds = next(iterator)
    if error_indication:
        print('Error: %s' % error_indication)
    elif error_status:
        print('Error: %s at %s' % (error_status.prettyPrint(), error_index and var_binds[int(error_index) - 1][0] or '?'))
    else:
        for var_bind in var_binds:
            print('RAM usage: %s' % var_bind.prettyPrint())
```

I researched on stackoverflow and other sites but found no solution for this kind of problem. I want to get a respone from the SNMP Agent.

Does anynone know how to fix this error?

Comment: Seems like `getCmd` is returning something (an `int`) that doesn't respond to `next()`. What is `getCmd` returning? I.e., what *is* the value of `iterator`?

Comment: The [docs](https://pysnmp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/hlapi/v3arch/asyncore/manager/cmdgen/getcmd.html) make it very clear that `getCmd()` returns an `int`. Were you expecting something different?

Comment: Seems you mixed up `asyncore` with `asyncio`.

Comment: @MichaelRuth I don't understand, why I can't iterate over an Int. Can you correct the code? I'm new to SNMP with Python, which is why I don't yet understand all the connections.

Comment: @MichaelButscher appears correct that you have a typo. It is impossible to iterate over an `int`, it is not an `iterable` and nothing will change this. Generally, only collections of things are iterable, but an `int` is a singleton. To answer your question specifically: an iterable must define `__iter__()`, `__next__()`, and `__next__()` must raise `StopIterationError` once the iterator is exhausted; `int` does none of these things.

Comment: What do you think it would mean to iterate over an `int`? It's not a collection of things. You can use it as an argument to `range()` to get a series of integers.

Comment: The code indicates that you followed a rather old document. Python 3.12 removed `asyncore`, so you shouldn't use it in any case either. To find the latest PySNMP docs and examples, you can try https://www.pysnmp.com/pysnmp/quick-start